# Required If Dependency in SQL

Tags: sql, required

I need to be able to restrict inserts into a table if a specified column is not provided.

Here's the catch, there is another column which is dependent on that column, that when provided, should enforce the required constraint.

I have looked at `CHECK` constraints in `CREATE TABLE` statements, but I do not know how to do an `IF THEN` statement that will check fieldA, then enforce required on fieldB.

Both columns are nullable and in some cases neither is required, but when fieldA is provided, I want to limit the database to only allow non null values for fieldB.

So for a literal example, here is my table called `Person` - it has the following columns:

```
PersonID INT IDENTITY
Name VARCHAR(50) NULL
Age INT NULL 
DateOfBirth VARCHAR(20) NULL
```

Now, if a record is attempted to be inserted into `Person` where `Age` (fieldA) is provided, I want to ensure that `DateOfBirth` (fieldB) is also provided.

This kind of validation is done from the app, but we also want it on our tables.

Comment: Can `DateOfBirth` be provided even if `Age` isn't? I.e. is the relationship between these columns symmetrical? (Accepting the points already given that we're not really talking about Age/DOB)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want a `check` constraint:

```
check ((DateOfBirth is null and age is null) or (DateOfBirth is not null and age is not null))
```

Note:

- DO NOT STORE DATES AS STRINGS.  Wow.  I put that in all-caps.
- Storing age is a bad idea.  It tends to change quite frequently.

Comment: All-caps isn't enough. You should even write the DO NOT STORE ... hint in bold face as well.

Comment: Thanks. This was just an example, the real table I want to add the constraint to is nothing like this.